# 10 bolt to 14 bolt semi-float 6 lug swap - C1500

Tags: rear-differential

This seems like a long shot, but here goes.. 
I have read a ton of information on various blogs about the 10 bolt to 14 bolt conversion. The problem is that there is a ton of conflicting information--partly due to the fact that some people don't know what they are talking about, people are not explicit with the exact application, and there are quite a few different '14 bolts' in circulation.

I want to upgrade the 10 bolt axel in my '93 C1500 (2X4) to a 14 bolt (OBS 90's model). I'm more interested in the most painless swap possible. I have narrowed it down to the 6 lug 14 bolt semi-float. These axels came in 2WD and 4WD configurations, apparently on some K1500's (very rare) and some 2500's (both 2 and 4WD).

Are the 14 bolt, 6 lug, 2WD and 4WD axels the same? I've read that the 4x4 axel is actually shorter than the 2wd, but can't confirm.

Comment: If you measure the distance from the inside of the backing plate (drum brakes) or rotor (disc brakes) side to side you can compare this measurement between 2wd and 4wd axles, if they are the same then the axles wiil be the same length.